# 'vue-stars' stars are not loading into the view

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

'vue-stars' was used to create a star rating system in my laravel 8 application. But stars are not loading into the view.

```
    <vue-stars
      name="demo"
      :active-color="#ffdd00"
      :inactive-color="#999999"
      :shadow-color="#ffff00"
      :hover-color="#dddd00"
      :max="5"
      :value="3"
      :readonly="false"
      :char="★"
      :inactive-char=""
      :class=""
     />
```

**imported in app.js**

```
import { VueStars } from "vue-stars";
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Are you registering the vue-stars component?

Comment: @YashMaheshwari You mean ?

Comment: @YashMaheshwari Please let me know...

Comment: Means something like `Vue.component('VueStars')`, also check if you are getting any error or warning on console.

Comment: @YashMaheshwari Yes i have done it "Vue.component("vue-stars", VueStars);".

And no errors in console. It does work in another page. But not in this purticular page.